# Deploy to Maven Central from a Gitlab CI workflow

Tags: gitlab-ci, maven-central

I maintain a few Java library projects on GitLab, which I build with a GitLab CI workflow and currently deploy to a GitLab Maven repository. Now I would like to deploy them to Maven Central instead, but have been unable to find any tutorials, examples or boilerplate code for doing so.

My current `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"

image: maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME"
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - public

.verify: &verify
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify'
  except:
    - master
    - dev

verify:jdk8:
  <<: *verify

# Deploy to GitLab's Maven Repository for `master` and `dev` branch
deploy:jdk8:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - if [ ! -f ci_settings.xml ];
        then echo "CI settings missing\! If deploying to GitLab Maven Repository, please see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html#creating-maven-packages-with-gitlab-cicd for instructions.";
      fi
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy -s ci_settings.xml'
  only:
    - master
    - dev

# Deploy Javadoc to GitLab Pages
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'mvn javadoc:javadoc -DadditionalJOption=-Xdoclint:none'
    - if [ -e public/javadoc/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME ];
        then rm -Rf public/javadoc/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME ;
      fi
    - 'mkdir -p public/javadoc/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME'
    - 'cp -r target/site/apidocs/* public/javadoc/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
    - master
    - dev
```

The closest I found was an instruction on [deploying to Artifactory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/artifactory_and_gitlab/index.html), but nothing about Maven Central. What is the procedure for Maven Central?

Comment: I've written about this on my blog at https://www.jvt.me/posts/2022/01/04/gitlab-ci-maven-signing-publish/ - there's a bit more work required to do the signing of the artefacts